# scope in oauth2 flow for google accounts without the corresponding product?

Tags: google-oauth

I am wondering if google oauth2 flow would throw an error when the requested scope is about a product the authorizing google account does NOT have. Or that is all managed by API access. Would really appreciate it if some information/clue can be shared.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me that google does not check user account capability in the oauth 2.0 flow. OAuth token is generated all fine for a user account without google EMM API enabled when scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidenterprise. API access is stopped with 403.

Just to share my findings